# How to extract a part of the filename from the `read.table` command and define as a new column

Tags: r, stringr

I'm looking for a way to automatically extract a part of the file name and populate a column with it while reading-in that file into R. Here's an example:

```
library(stringr)
df <- read.table("[MYPATH]/Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt", 
                 comment.char = "", header = FALSE, quote="", sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  mutate(Rec = str_extract(myFileNames[1], ".*\\d"))
```

This however works only because I have prepared in advance the vector `myFileNames` with all relevant file names and happen to know that the file name `Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt"` is the first element in that vector.

How can I achieve the same result without this detour to an external vector?

Comment: Just wrap your `read.table` and `mutate` calls in a function that takes the file name as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment (untested code):

```
readFileAndAddFileNameAsColumn <- function(fName) {
  read.table(
    fName, 
    comment.char = "", 
    header = FALSE, 
    quote="", 
    sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8"
  ) %>%
  mutate(Rec = str_extract(fName, ".*\\d"))
}

readFileAndAddFileNameAsColumn("[MYPATH]/Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt")
```

Alternatively, you may be able to use the `.id` argument of `bind_rows` if you pass your `myFileNamesList` to `lapply`.  Something like

```
lapply(
  myFileNamesList,
  read.table,
  comment.car = "",
  header = FALSE,
  quote = "",
  sep = "\t",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  encoding = "UTF-8"
) %>%
bind_rows(.id = "Rec")
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply could pipe into `cbind`.

```
> lapply(v, read.table, sep='\t', comment.char='', encoding='UTF-8') |> Map(f=cbind, Rec=v)
[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4                            Rec
1  1  4  7 10 Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt
2  2  5  8 11 Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt
3  3  6  9 12 Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4                            Rec
1  1  4  7 10 Mon1_2016-10-07_@exyz66698.txt
2  2  5  8 11 Mon1_2016-10-07_@exyz66698.txt
3  3  6  9 12 Mon1_2016-10-07_@exyz66698.txt
```

---

*Data:*

```
write.table(data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), 'Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep='\t')
write.table(data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), 'Mon1_2016-10-07_@exyz66698.txt', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep='\t')
v <- c("Mon1_2016-10-06_@exyz66698.txt", "Mon1_2016-10-07_@exyz66698.txt")
```